# UIAccessibility turn of/on voice objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiaccessibility

Anybody know if it is possible to turn `on/off accessibility (voice-over)` in code?
I'm programming apps for blind people and in one instance we need to quickly toggle the `on/off` for the accessiblity voice over.

`Apple` Docs don't mention if this is possible or not.

Comment: Why do you need to disable VoiceOver?

Comment: At a certain point in time, a user control is read by voice over when our text to speech engine is already speaking. Since we cannot know if voice-over is speaking or when it is done, I would disable voice over alltogether and just when our text to speech engine has finished, enable voice-over again.

Comment: It gets complex because the app is using voice-over to read the screen elements and a text to speech engine to read text in a text control. Right now, they are all speaking together and it gets confusing for our users.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no public API to do that. It's a feature controlled by the user.